# How to redirect to webpage by clicking on image without using anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a image. I would like to redirect to new webpage when someone clicks on the image. I know this will be possible by using anchor tag. But i want to do this without using anchor tag. Below my code.

```
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/368px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png" alt="Google image">
```

Comment: Where is your code? This is just an image tag. Did you try anything yet?

Comment: Sorry, updated now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the one tool purposely designed for this task?

Comment: Yes, for my task.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript's Event Listener.

```js
document.querySelector("#imgID").addEventListener("click", () => {
      window.location.href = "http://google.com";
});
```

Comment: Thank You Ahsan Khan! this answer worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery to redirect using on click event.

```
$( "#imageId" ).click(function() {
  window.location.href = "RedirectPage";
});
```